# CSS @page rule not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have declared a CSS `@page` rule. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer 11. If it doesn't work, what solutions should I be using instead?

Comment: It looks like this should work in ie 8? :D http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530841(v=vs.85).aspx Just leave IE for everyone's sake.

Comment: Are there any solutions to set the page layouts for printing?

Comment: Can you show your code exactly?  Are your @ rules nested?  ie, is @page inside an @media?  Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869038/ie11-ignoring-page-rule

Comment: I have fixed my problem by editing the print setting up on IE, now it work, but another problem :(

I use javascript to print iframes on IE, each iframe has the long more than one page, but it just show one page for each iframe? It work fine on Chrome, but not on IE 11. Please take a look my code at: http://jsfiddle.net/7LLut34q/5/